# What weather products do you use to determine whether or not a flight is safe?

Tags: weather

There are many weather products available on AviationWeather.gov and many other sites. What do you use for preflight planning?

Comment: This is a duplicate of *several* questions -- See Also: [What weather sources are approved by the NWS](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1648/) ; [Where can I get additional weather information for flight planning](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/595/) ; [What FAA weather data is available on icing](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21270/)

Comment: (If there is something you need to know that's not covered in those questions please try editing your question to be more specific)